# Can't upload audio file with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I have a working piece of python:

```
url = "abc.com"
data = open('speech.wav', 'rb').read()
res = requests.post(url=url,
                    data=data,
                    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'})
```

which allows me to upload a wav file as a post request to the server. However, the below NodeJS code

```
var req = request.post('abc.com', function(err, resp, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error!');
    } else {
        console.log('URL: ' + body);
    }
});
var form = req.form();
form.append('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
form.append('data', fs.createReadStream('speech.wav'));
```

returns "Unsupported Media Type: The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method."

What am I doing wrong on Node?

Answer (score 2):

Try to send content-type as header, rather than in form. The content-type in form is considered for multipart form data.